# How to change the default baudrate of raspberry pi's serial port?

Tags: rpi.gpio, serial-console, xbee

Iam getting junk values that is being read by rpi's serial port. Rpi is reading data through its serial port from a zigbee which is connected to the ttyAMA0 of rpi. In the python program, i've specified the baudrate as 9600. In the sender end also, its specified as 9600. Can anyone plz help me out cyting what can be the possible solution for this?

Comment: take a look at this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1094/56

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may not just be the baudrate.

By default the Pi outputs console messages on the serial port, which is used by few. It's possible that these are interfering with your attempt to use the serial port.

Try to modify `/boot/cmdline.txt` deleting `console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1`

Answer (score 1):

this is set in `/etc/inittab` and can be modified by changing the getty settings to whatever you desire.

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 tty1
```

becomes

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 9600 tty1
```

Have a look at the `getty` and `inittab` documentation if you have any more questions.